# Scala Process with pipe

Tags: scala, process, escaping

I am trying to run a bash command like this one in scala:

```
cat "example file.txt" | grep abc
```

Scala has a special syntax for process piping, so this was my first approach:

```
val filename = "example file.txt"
(Process(Seq("cat", filename)) #| Process(Seq("grep", "abc"))).run()
```

As far as I understand, this executes the first process, reads the output back to scala and feeds it to the second process. The problem is that, for performance reasons, I would like to execute both processes without leaving the terminal. The file is huge and I don't need the whole output, that's why I am using grep in the first place. So, my second approach was this one:

```
val filename = "example file.txt"
(Process(Seq("bash", "-c", "cat " + filename + " | grep abc"))).run()
```

The problem here is that it breaks if the filename has spaces. I could try to escape spaces, but I would rather have scala doing it for me (there are many other characters that I would also need to escape).

Is there another way to run this command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy enough to escape the filename:

```
val escapedFilename = "'" + filename.replace("'", "'\\''") + "'"
```

But the right way to do this is to pass the filename directly to grep:

```
Process(Seq("grep", "abc", filename)).run()
```

Which is equivalent to this in the shell:

```
grep abc "example file.txt"
```

Comment: Ok, you're right about passing the filename to grep. The command I am actually trying to run is a little more complicated than that, it was just an example, I can't ignore the pipe. But thanks for the escaping hint, I'll try it.

Comment: Solved the problem, thanks. Manual escaping is much simpler than I thought